# Can't load class on Slim 3

Tags: php, slim, psr-4

I'm trying to load my custom classes for the model on Slim 3 (using the skeleton) so I made this:

In app/composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\Classes\\": "/src/classes"
    }
},
```

In routes.php I have this setting:

```
<?php

use Slim\Http\Request;
use Slim\Http\Response;
use Slim\Container;


// Routes
$app->get('/sugiere', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    // Sample log message
    $this->logger->info("Slim-Skeleton '/' route");
    $cat_mapper = new \App\Classes\CategoryMapper($this->db);
    $comuna_mapper = new \App\Classes\ComunaMapper($this->db);
    $lang_mapper = new \App\Classes\LanguageMapper($this->db);
    $netw_mapper = new \App\Classes\NetworkMapper($this->db);
    $com_list = $com_mapper->getComunaList();
    $cat_list = $cat_mapper->getCategoryList();
    $lang_list = $lang_mapper->getLangList();
    $netw_list = $netw_mapper->getNetworkList();
```

By the way I added to all classes a namespace App\Classes on top.

Comment: What **exactly** is the error message?

Comment: The application could not run because of the following error:

Details
Type: Error
Message: Class 'App\Classes\CategoryMapper' not found
File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/santiago/src/routes.php
Line: 13

Comment: Have you run `composer dump-autoload` after adding your `autoload` configuration to `composer.json`? See https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your path `/src/classes` looks incorrect. It's unlikely your `src` directory is in the filesystem root.

Change your `composer.json` file to

```
"autoload": {
  "psr-4": {
    "App\\Classes\\": "src/classes/"
  }
}
```

and run

```sh
composer dump-autoload
```

to re-generate the `autoload.php` file.

See https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

Comment: I changed it but I get the same error. I get a 500 error.

Comment: @ffuentes changed it to _what_, exactly? Please update your question with the configuration and code you're currently using.

Comment: @ffuentes Could you also please show a screenshot of your `src/classes` directory contents and the namespace and class definition in one of your files, eg `src/classes/CategoryMapper.php`

Comment: Now I got it. I changed the route and wrote the use statement above and when calling the method.